# index.jsp file not loading

Tags: jsp, tomcat

i am new in JSP and tomcat. I add index.jsp file in tomcar/webapp/project folder but not loading index.jsp.
the error is:

```
type Exception report

message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:176)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.index_jsp
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:131)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:62)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:171)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/8.0.27 logs.
```

and the index.jsp is :

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
   <head><title>Hello World</title></head>

   <body>
      Hello World!<br/>

   </body>
</html>
```

.how to fix it ?

Comment: Tomcat 8.0.x has reached end of life. You need to upgrade to a supported version of Tomcat. For this issue, are there any error messages in the logs?

Comment: I use tomcat 8.0.2